# Saving date to datetime throws Datetime field overflow

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am attempting to save a date and I get the error,
"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Datetime field overflow. Fractional second precision exceeds the scale specified in the parameter binding."

The column I am saving is a **Datetime** column in sql named **rowUpdateDate**.

The value I am setting to the row comes from the vb datetime method Now().

This code was working until an ODBC driver was updated on the server.

```js
rs("rowUpdateDate") = now()
rs.ActiveConnection = cn
rs.UpdateBatch adAffectAll
```

Comment: See if this helps: `rs("rowUpdateDate") = FormatDateTime(now(), 0)`

Comment: So which is this? ASP.NET or ASP Classic?  Two very different animals

Comment: @leeharvey1 the same error still occurred no matter how the date was formatted.

Comment: @StephenR Its classic

Comment: I believe `FormatDateTime()` fails because it uses am/pm for the time. A SQL timestamp should be 24-hr format.  I personally have a custom function to convert a datetime to a SQL "timestamp" format

Comment: @StephenR you can enter your own format into the function. Also no matter what the format the error still occurred.

Comment: What happens if you hard code it?  Try `rs("rowUpdateDate") = "2019-12-17 13:35:00"`.  Same error?

Comment: @StephenR same error.  Also I already resolved the issue and the issue is related to the driver after I tried everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the driver update, updating the table by using the record set no longer works.  This could be due to the addition of datetime2, but unsure.

What worked was changing the code to use a SQL update statement to update the table instead of the record.

```js
updateSQL="UPDATE contractorApplicationProcess SET "
updateSQL=updateSQL & "DMID='" & Request("DMID") & "',"
updateSQL=updateSQL & "RecruitingID='" & Request("RecruiterMembership") & "',"
updateSQL=updateSQL & "contractorID='" & Request("contrID") & "',"
updateSQL=updateSQL & "rowUpdateDate='" & now() & "',"
updateSQL=updateSQL & "rowUpdateID='" & ResourceID & "'"
updateSQL=updateSQL & " WHERE contractorApplicationProcessID='" & clng(contrApplProcessID) & "'"

cn.Execute updateSQL
```

Comment: Two comments here: In ASP Classic it's more efficient to use one long string than keep concatenating pieces as you do here. Better to use the line break `_`.  Second: *parameterize your queries*. Concatenating user input into a query string this way is a massive security vulnerability. https://bobby-tables.com/